# Instantiating a class for text analytics

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I’ve found this code, a Python Class which takes a WhatsApp conversation text file processes and generates a Chat class which I can interact with. Things like generate charts, the response matrix etc.:

```
import re
import time
import pandas as pd
import dateutil
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class WppAnalyser:
    def open_file(self):
        x = open(self.filename,'r')
        y = x.read()
        content = y.splitlines()
        return content

    def ismessage(self,str):
        patterns = {

        "hor1":r'w{3}s{1}[0-9]{1,2},s{1}d{4},s{1}d{2}:d{2}', 
        "hor2":r'w{3}s{1}[0-9]{1,2},s{1}d{2}:d{2}', 
        "imp2":r'd{1,2}sw{3}sd{2}:d{2}', 
        "imp1":r'd{1,2}sw{3}sd{4}sd{2}:d{2}'

         }
        for key in patterns:
            result = re.search(patterns[key], str)
            if result and str.count(':') >=2:
                name_start = str.find("-")+2
                first_colon = str.find(":")
                name_end = str.find(":", first_colon+1)
                name=str[name_start:name_end]
                message=str[name_end+1:]
                return [name, message, result.group()]
                return ["","",str]

    def process(self,content):
        j = 1
        df = pd.DataFrame(index = range(1, len(content)+1), columns=[ 'Name', 'Message', 'date_string'])
        for i in content:
            results = self.ismessage(i)
            if results[0] != "":
                df.ix[j]=results
            else:
                df.ix[j]['Name']=df.ix[j-1]['Name']
                df.ix[j]['date_string']=df.ix[j-1]['date_string']
                df.ix[j]['Message']=results[2]
            j = j+1
            df['Time'] = df['date_string'].map(lambda x: dateutil.parser.parse(x))
            df['Day'] = df['date_string'].map(lambda x: dateutil.parser.parse(x).strftime("%a"))
            df['Date'] = df['date_string'].map(lambda x:dateutil.parser.parse(x).strftime("%x"))
            df['Hour'] = df['date_string'].map(lambda x:dateutil.parser.parse(x).strftime("%H"))
```

How would I run these functions together, passing self in each function is confusing me. What would a main function looks like here?

I have to instantiate WppAnalyser class, right? So far, I tried this for the first method:

```
class Chat:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = open("chatPPL.txt", "r")
        self.y = y
```

Comment: holy guacamole, that is some inefficient `pandas`

Comment: But anyway, I am not sure what your question is. Perhaps it's best not to use OOP until you have a firm grasp on it, the good thing about Python is that you almost never *have* to write  a class definition...

Comment: I'd like some help to instantiate that class. I find a way to use its methods, of course, using oop